# Total possible permutations with certain restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How to solve such questions in which we are given $N$ distinct numbers i.e $1$ to $N$ and also given certain restrictions like  $(x,y) , (x,z) , (z,x) , (z,a) , (b,c)$ and so on should never occur simultaneously.

For example:

$N=4$ and $(1,2) , (2,3) , (3,4)$ should never come together.

**Answer:** There are only $2$ possible permutations:
$2 4 1 3 $  and   $3 1 4 2$.

Is there any general way to solve such type of questions with larger values and more restrictions?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest in my opinion would be to use Inclusion-Exclusion.

For your example of permutations of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ avoiding substrings $(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)$, let $U$ be the set of all possible permutations of $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Let $A_{(1,2)}$ be the set of permutations which **do** contain a substring $(1,2)$, $A_{(2,3)}$ be the set of permutations which **do** contain a substring $(2,3)$, etc...

You are asking how to count $|U\setminus (A_{(1,2)}\cup A_{(2,3)}\cup A_{(3,4)})|$

By inclusion-exclusion we have the count being:

$=|U|-|A_{(1,2)}|-|A_{(2,3)}|-|A_{(3,4)}|+|A_{(1,2)}\cap A_{(2,3)}|+|A_{(1,2)}\cap A_{(3,4)}|+|A_{(2,3)}\cap A_{(3,4)}|-|A_{(1,2)}\cap A_{(2,3)}\cap A_{(3,4)}|$

---

How do we count something like $|A_{(1,2)}|$?  Well, this is counting the number of ways of permuting the elements $\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $1$ is always followed by $2$.  Let us imagine then that $1$ and $2$ are tied together, so we are instead trying to permute the set of elements $\{~^1~_2,3,4\}$.

Similarly $A_{(1,2)}\cap A_{(2,3)}$ are the permutations where $1$ is followed by $2$ is further followed by $3$, so it is as though we are permuting the set $\{~^12_3,4\}$

We have then the total number of permutations of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ avoiding $(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)$ as substrings are:

$4!-3\cdot 3!+3\cdot 2!-1=11$

---

Given that you counted only two total, perhaps instead your interpretation of the problem is that $12$ is not a substring **and** $21$ is not a substring.  The way I originally read the question was that $2143$ was an allowable permutation since $1$ is never followed by $2$, $2$ is not followed by $3$, and $3$ is not followed by $4$.  If we were to change it so that $(1,2)$ being bad means both $1$ is neither followed by $2$ nor following $2$, then it would be as though we had six conditions to worry about.  The inclusion-exclusion will seem a great deal longer, but the same concept applies.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way, especially because you have not said what sort of restrictions might be applied.  You can either count the permutations directly or subtract the disallowed ones from the total.  Interlocking restrictions like your example (where $2,3$ are in more than one restriction) can make it a bunch of work.  For your case of  (1,2) ; (2,3) ; (3,4) should never come together but larger $N$, I would start by making cases for where $2$ and $3$ come.  We can put $2$ in two ends or $N-2$ middles.  If $2$ is on an end, $3$ can go on the other end (one way) or $N-3$ middles.  If $2$ is in the middle, $3$ can go ...  Then given the cases so far, you can find the number of places for $1,4$.  The rest of the numbers can go in any permutation.